# Conta com dados recebidos e dados do mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Boa tarde, é o seguinte no meu projeto eu necessito de fazer uma conta para no final ter o resultado para o cliente saber quanto tem de pagar, mas eu não estou a conseguir fazer essa conta.
No meu caso, eu peço os dias e depois o quarto vai ter um preço (que neste caso ja esta registado no mysql) e eu quero ir buscar esses dados ao mysql e fazer a conta por exemplo (montante = preco * dias).

```
<html>
<title>Dados enviados</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/hospederegisto.css" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />

<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="logoherdade.png"></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="middle">
        <br><br><p>Obrigado pela sua preferência!</p>
        <p>A partir deste momento, tem 24 horas para efetuar o pagamento e completar a sua estadia.</p>
        <br>
        <table>
            <tr>
            <td>Entidade:</td>
            <td>00000</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td>Referência:</td>
            <td>000 000 000</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td>Montante:</td>
            <td><?php $montante; ?>€</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br><br>

        <?php
            // Conecta à base de dados
            include ('ligar.php');

            $sql = "select preco from casa where num_casa = 1";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);


            //Variáveis dos formulários
            $nome=$_POST['nome'];
            $sobrenome=$_POST['sobrenome'];
            $email=$_POST['email'];
            $telefone=$_POST['telefone'];
            $contribuinte=$_POST['contribuinte'];
            $cc=$_POST['cc'];
            $morada=$_POST['morada'];
            $data_entrada=$_POST['data_entrada'];
            $data_saida=$_POST['data_saida'];

            $preco = $row["preco"];

            $diferenca = strtotime($data_saida) - strtotime($data_entrada);
            $num_dias = floor($diferenca / (60*60*24));

            $montante = ($num_dias * $preco);

            echo "<b>Nome:</b> ".$nome."<br>";
            echo "<b>Sobrenome:</b> ".$sobrenome."<br>";
            echo "<b>E-mail:</b> ".$email."<br>";
            echo "<b>Telefone:</b> ".$telefone."<br>";
            echo "<b>Contribuinte:</b> ".$contribuinte."<br>";
            echo "<b>Cartão de Cidadão:</b> ".$cc."<br>";
            echo "<b>Morada:</b> ".$morada."<br>";
            echo "<b>Data entrada:</b> ".$data_entrada."<br>";
            echo "<b>Data saida:</b> ".$data_saida."<br>";
            echo "<b>Número de dias:</b> ".$num_dias."<br>";

            //Vai registar os dados inseridos pelo utilizador
            $sql = "INSERT INTO hospede (nome, sobrenome, email, telefone, contribuinte, cc, morada, data_entrada, data_saida, num_dias)
            VALUES ('$nome', '$sobrenome', '$email', '$telefone', '$contribuinte', '$cc', '$morada', '$data_entrada', '$data_saida', '$num_dias')";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
            if ($result)
            echo "";
            else
            echo "Erro ao tentar registar dados na base de dados!";
        ?>
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="Imprimir" onClick="window.print()"/>
        <a href="../herdade.html">Voltar</a>
    </div>
```

Alguém pode editar, não sei como formatar.

Comment: Por favor, forneça um trecho de código na pergunta, ao invés de uma imagem.

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485

Comment: Já está, estou à espera que alguem formate o meu texto.

Answer (score -1):

Olá,
Caso o `$row["preco"]` esteja retornando o valor correto, tenta mudar a ordem de atribuição de:
`$row["preco"] = $preco;`
para:
`$preco = $row["preco"];`
Caso o `$row["preco"]` não esteja retornando, tem algo de errado na sql.

Comment: É bem isso, só inverter que dá certo.

Comment: Obrigado, de momento não está a mostrar qualquer erro. Mas não estou a conseguir mostrar a variável aqui (<td>Montante:</td><td><?php $montante; ?>€</td>).

Comment: `$preco = 2.50;
$data_saida = date('Y-m-d');//peguei data atual
$data_entrada = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-3 day", strtotime($data_saida)));//peguei data a data de saida - 3 dias
$diferenca = strtotime($data_saida) - strtotime($data_entrada); 
$num_dias = floor($diferenca / (60*60*24));
$montante = ($num_dias * $preco);

var_dump($montante);`
Conforme o trecho de código, citado a cima é uma copia do seu, setando os valores, e esta funcionando, verifique se todos os valores estão sendo preenchido.

Comment: Porque atribuíste o (2.5) à variavel $preco? Supostamente essa variável era para ir buscar à base de dados... Acho que a única coisa que me falta mesmo é conseguir por o resultado do $num_dias * $preco na tabela.

Comment: Esses valore foi setado, manualmente para testar, o codigo, a sua `preco` ou `num_dias` deve estar sem valor ou com valor erado.
Valide, se estão sendo preenchido.

Comment: Vou testar, já agora "<td><?php $montante; ?>€</td>" isto está certo?

Comment: Não, para imprimir pode fazer `<?=$montante?>€` ou `<?php echo $montante; ?>€` eu prefiro usar da primeira forma.

Comment: Esta me a dar este erro: Notice: Undefined variable: montante in C:\xampp\htdocs\PAP\administrador\hospederegisto.php on line 33

Comment: Você esta colocando para "imprimir" a variável depois do código PHP ??? se tiver o git do projeto e puder disponibilizar posso ver melhor o que está ocorrendo....Mas o erro é que a variável não foi definida ainda.

Comment: Ahhhhh, erro meu mesmo, o código estava depois então ele não devia estar associando, obrigado Felipe e a todos os que ajudaram.

Answer (score -1):

Para esta situação, funcionar, substitua esta linha:

```
mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

por

```
mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Desta maneira a chave do array vai ser devolvida pelo valor do nome de campo (preco) da maneira que veio ele retorna somente um índice numérico da posição no array.